# Sparql optional properties

Tags: rdf, sparql

Is there a better way to express the following query that uses several **optional**s? When there are lots of properties, this quickly becomes error prone.

```sql
SELECT * WHERE {
  BIND(:London AS ?source)
  OPTIONAL{ ?source rdfs:label ?o .}
  OPTIONAL{?source rdfs:comment ?i . }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do much better than this, actually.  The only thing I'd do differently is to use **values** to specify the value of **?source**, rather than **bind**:

```sql
select * where {
  values ?source { dbpedia:London }
  optional { ?source rdfs:label   ?o }
  optional { ?source rdfs:comment ?i }
}
```

If you're willing to process your data a bit differently, you could use a query where the properties are specified with values, as well:

```sql
select * where {
  values ?source { dbpedia:London }
  values ?property { rdfs:label rdfs:comment }
  ?source ?property ?value
}
```

Of course, if you do this, then you trade the number of columns for the number of rows, but if there are multiple values for any of the properties, you still probably are better of.  For instance, in the first case, if London has just one label and one comment, you get:

```
source    label        commment
------------------------------------
London    "the label"  "the comment"
```

But if you have two label and three comments, you'll have six (= two × three) rows:

```
source    label     commment
------------------------------------
London    "label1"  "comment1"
London    "label1"  "comment2"
London    "label1"  "comment3"
London    "label2"  "comment1"
London    "label2"  "comment2"
London    "label2"  "comment3"
```

In the second case, if you have one label and one comment, you have two rows:

```
source    property      value 
------------------------------------
London    rdfs:label    "label1"
London    rdfs:comment  "comment1"
```

But if you have two labels and three comments, you end up with just five (= 2 + 3) rows:

```
source    property      value 
------------------------------------
London    rdfs:label    "label1"
London    rdfs:label    "label2"
London    rdfs:comment  "comment1"
London    rdfs:comment  "comment2"
London    rdfs:comment  "comment3"
```

So, if there can be multiple values for properties (which is very much the case in DBpedia data), enumerating the properties that you want with **values** may be less error prone (no **optional** blocks, and you get to write the properties all in the same place), and may give you fewer rows to worry about.  The downside is that you'll have to process the outputs and look at the property in each row;  you don't have a separate column for each property value.